# How to get properties in JSValue that is applied ToObject()?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I use JavaScriptCore in my program developed by Xamarin.iOS.
I want to get properties names in JSValue instance.

I tried `JSValue.GetProperty`, `JSValue.GetValueAt`.
But these method only can get property values.
I just want to know that what properties are in JSValue instance.

here is sample,

```
var test = {
  a: 12,
  b: "this is b."
  c: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I could get `test` object by `JSValue.GetProperty(string key)`.

But couldn't get `a`, `b`, `c` from `test` object.

How do I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer [Here](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53797/jsvalue%E3%81%8C%E3%82%82%E3%81%A4%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%91%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E5%90%8D%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84).

```cs
if (test.IsObject)
{
    var dict = test.ToDictionary();
    var keys = dict.Keys;
    foreach( var key in keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key+":"+dict[key]);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("`test` is not an object");
}
```

Use `ToDictionary()` method to **JSValue**(**NSObject**).

I could use `test` object as [NSDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsdictionary?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12).

Answer (score 2):

> But couldn't get a, b, c from test object.

You can get all the keys using the **for loop** and the **hasOwnProperty** method.As follow:

```
var test = {
  a: 12,
  b: "this is b."
  c: [1, 2, 3]
}
var keys1 = [];
for (var p1 in test ) {
    if (test.hasOwnProperty(p1))
        keys1.push(p1);
}
alert(keys1); // a,b,c
```

This problem seems not about Xamarin, next time you can ask this with **JS** Tags.